# Why is $(window).scrollTop(); reporting a zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function inside $(window).bind('scroll',function(){}); that is dependent on var scrollHeight - but scrollHeight keeps reporting 0

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('hello');
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).bind('scroll',function(){
        console.log('scroll height =', scrollHeight)
    });
});
```

Take a look at the fiddle and open up your console to see scrollHeight = 0 no matter how far you scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/VJ2Z3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/B4DB9/)***

You are never updating `scrollHeight`. Because it is only read once, you just get that constant value every time the scroll event fires.

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    //update the value inside of the event handler
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log('scroll height =', scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: `.bind()` in year 2014? o_O PS: oh I see, just copied the OP's code

Comment: @zerkms - Just being consistent with the OP's post. :)